# Spring slow performance at "Web Framework Benchmarks" website

Tags: spring, spring-boot

It looks like the performance of Spring (Boot) is relatively low compare to other frameworks at "Web Framework Benchmarks" website [Web Framework Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r10&hw=ec2&test=json). I looked at the source code ([JSON serialization](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/frameworks/Java/spring/src/main/java/com/techempower/spring/web/HelloController.java)) and could not find anything odd. So I am wondering whether the low performance is caused by Tomcat or by the framework itself?

Answer (score 7):

Slow? It seems to be more or less in the middle of the ranks. Which doesn't seem too bad considering that it is actually a framework. The definition of framework for that set of benchmarks is *very* liberal, given that it includes benchmarks for a pretty raw Undertow application and another for a raw Servlet.

But given that the Spring benchmark itself is running on Undertow, it wouldn't be Tomcat causing the issue. :)

Looking at the source for the various benchmarks, they are really not comparing like for like. For example, the Spring benchmark project builds a reasonably standard multi-tiered application with ORM entities mapped with JPA and Hibernate, re-usable repository classes, etc.

On the other hand the Wicket application just has a controller with a JDBC call. It even uses a hand-cranked template for generating JSON. You could write a Spring application that way if you wanted to, but nobody would be impressed.

The Undertow benchmark again does little more than query a database with JDBC and spit out a response. It's not surprising that it would be faster than itself with a full stack framework running on it.

Of course, they hopefully get you to think about your priorities in writing an application. Do you want a full stack framework, which lets you write less code, provides various security features, helps you to achieve code re-use, and make your application more testable and maintainable? Or are you willing to sacrifice all that for speed?

Comment: I agree that comparing plain servlet like Undertow with Spring is not fair, but there are other frameworks there like Dropwizard with better performance (it uses Jetty not Tomcat).

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the Spring benchmark uses Undertow - not Jetty or Tomcat.

Comment: As you mention Dropwizard, it's probably worth pointing out that the Spring benchmark has better results on the 'Fortunes' benchmark. I would recommend looking at the individual benchmark applications if you wish to understand why one framework might be faster than another at a particular thing: https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks

Comment: I think they use blocking drivers for all benchmark. Maybe DeferredResult + async driver for DB would give better numbers.

Comment: @PeiSong given that the JDBC spec is blocking by design. There are also no true non-blocking JDBC drivers available at this time.